# Префикс и постфикс в С#

Tags: c#

```
    int o;
    int h = 2;
    o = ++h * h++;  //(9  - C+) ( 9 - C#)
```

---

```
    int z = 2;
    z = ++z * z++;  //(10 - C+) ( 9 - C#)
```

---

```
    int y = 2;
    y *= ++y * y++; //(28 - C+) (18 - C#)
```

Разница между **o** и **z** показывает, что у С++ правая и левая части "=" связаны прямой сcылкой, а в С# вроде бы левая **z** сама по себе и на нее **z++** после расчетов не влияет.

Если смотреть на **y**, то там видно еще лучше, что левая часть у С# это совсем другая переменная, на которую не влияет правая часть.

Так что чтобы разобраться как оно работает по одиночке – очень сложно.

Мне говорили на форумах так:
++ и – это просто сокращенные названия методов, перегруженные операторы внутри компилятора. Они вызываются все одинаково без всяких там кто первый, а кто второй, и типа просто одна перегрузка возвращает увеличенную/уменьшенную себя, а другая старую копию.

Но если смотреть на **y** то видно, что это не так (в конце умножения в С++ добавляется постфиксная +1, но в С# она не учитывается, потому что левая часть уже не учитывает что было в правой).

Вообще кажется, что в этом случае, когда слева и справа одна переменная – там какая-то махинация со ссылками на **valueType**

Также это утверждение фейлится, если попытаться поменять местами **y++ + ++y**

Поэтому на самом деле неизвестно, что там происходит.
Возможно это работает (то как говорят на форумах) только тогда, когда ты **сам** перегружаешь эти методы и хочешь, чтобы они работали похоже на родные ++ и -- .
Но похоже для родных Value типов это не так.

Comment: Короче, еще одна магия от C#, переворачивающая все с ног на голову

Comment: `k = ++h * h++;` `z = ++z * z++;` один я не вижу разницы? Почему для одного и того же выражения в C++ разные значения? Вы либо где-то опечатались, либо ваши тесты кривые.

Comment: В первом случае значение присваивается другой переменной. А во втором - участвует всего 1 переменная

Comment: Вопрос то собственно в чём? Тут вся тонкость в деталях реализации конкретного компилятора - в какой момент берётся какая часть вычисляемого выражения. И как, к примеру, реализована конструкция `y *= x`, её же можно написать как `y = y * x`, а можно и как `y = x * y`, вроде бы разницы никакой, но если порядок вычисления важен, то разница уже есть. В целом же я не понимаю, какой смысл в изучении таких примеров, кроме того, чтобы поломать голову над тем, в каком порядке идут вычисления. В промышленном коде такое лучше просто не делать, код должен работать предсказуемо, а не вот это вот всё.

Comment: Главное, что я это заметил. На примере четко видно, что лучше не использовать такие ребусы и вообще инкременты где либо кроме как в отдельной строке. Раньше говорили, что нельзя больше одного на операцию. Но теперь я думаю, что лучше вообще не делать в каком либо выражении. Никогда не знаешь что под капотом. Я недавно боялся вставить его в условие, потом вставил. Теперь думаю обратно сделать. Лучше пару строчек больше - зато без магии

Answer (score 3, accepted):

С точки зрения компилятора всё просто.

Написал такой код, который, я надеюсь, правильно повторяет ваш пример.

```
public int M1() {
    int x = 2;
    int y = ++x * x++;
    return y;
}

public int M2() {
    int x = 2;
    x = ++x * x++;
    return x;
}

public int M3() {
    int x = 2;
    x *= ++x * x++;
    return x;
}
```

И скомпилировал

```
C.M1()
    L0000: mov eax, 9
    L0005: ret

C.M2()
    L0000: mov eax, 9
    L0005: ret

C.M3()
    L0000: mov eax, 0x12
    L0005: ret
```

Но это была оптимизированная сборка, давайте отладочную посмотрим

```
C.M1()
    L0000: push rbp
    L0001: push rdi
    L0002: push rsi
    L0003: sub rsp, 0x40
    L0007: lea rbp, [rsp+0x50]
    L000c: mov rsi, rcx
    L000f: lea rdi, [rbp-0x24]
    L0013: mov ecx, 0x5
    L0018: xor eax, eax
    L001a: rep stosd
    L001c: mov rcx, rsi
    L001f: mov [rbp+0x10], rcx
    L0023: cmp dword [rip+0xbeabe], 0x0
    L002a: jz L0031
    L002c: call 0x7ffba9596980
    L0031: nop
    L0032: mov dword [rbp-0x14], 0x2
    L0039: mov eax, [rbp-0x14]
    L003c: inc eax
    L003e: mov [rbp-0x20], eax
    L0041: mov eax, [rbp-0x14]
    L0044: inc eax
    L0046: mov [rbp-0x14], eax
    L0049: mov eax, [rbp-0x14]
    L004c: mov [rbp-0x24], eax
    L004f: mov eax, [rbp-0x14]
    L0052: inc eax
    L0054: mov [rbp-0x14], eax
    L0057: mov eax, [rbp-0x20]
    L005a: imul eax, [rbp-0x24]
    L005e: mov [rbp-0x18], eax
    L0061: mov eax, [rbp-0x18]
    L0064: mov [rbp-0x1c], eax
    L0067: nop
    L0068: jmp L006a
    L006a: mov eax, [rbp-0x1c]
    L006d: lea rsp, [rbp-0x10]
    L0071: pop rsi
    L0072: pop rdi
    L0073: pop rbp
    L0074: ret

C.M2()
    L0000: push rbp
    L0001: push rdi
    L0002: push rsi
    L0003: sub rsp, 0x30
    L0007: lea rbp, [rsp+0x40]
    L000c: mov rsi, rcx
    L000f: lea rdi, [rbp-0x20]
    L0013: mov ecx, 0x4
    L0018: xor eax, eax
    L001a: rep stosd
    L001c: mov rcx, rsi
    L001f: mov [rbp+0x10], rcx
    L0023: cmp dword [rip+0xbea2e], 0x0
    L002a: jz L0031
    L002c: call 0x7ffba9596980
    L0031: nop
    L0032: mov dword [rbp-0x14], 0x2
    L0039: mov eax, [rbp-0x14]
    L003c: inc eax
    L003e: mov [rbp-0x1c], eax
    L0041: mov eax, [rbp-0x14]
    L0044: inc eax
    L0046: mov [rbp-0x14], eax
    L0049: mov eax, [rbp-0x14]
    L004c: mov [rbp-0x20], eax
    L004f: mov eax, [rbp-0x14]
    L0052: inc eax
    L0054: mov [rbp-0x14], eax
    L0057: mov eax, [rbp-0x1c]
    L005a: imul eax, [rbp-0x20]
    L005e: mov [rbp-0x14], eax
    L0061: mov eax, [rbp-0x14]
    L0064: mov [rbp-0x18], eax
    L0067: nop
    L0068: jmp L006a
    L006a: mov eax, [rbp-0x18]
    L006d: lea rsp, [rbp-0x10]
    L0071: pop rsi
    L0072: pop rdi
    L0073: pop rbp
    L0074: ret

C.M3()
    L0000: push rbp
    L0001: push rdi
    L0002: push rsi
    L0003: sub rsp, 0x40
    L0007: lea rbp, [rsp+0x50]
    L000c: mov rsi, rcx
    L000f: lea rdi, [rbp-0x24]
    L0013: mov ecx, 0x5
    L0018: xor eax, eax
    L001a: rep stosd
    L001c: mov rcx, rsi
    L001f: mov [rbp+0x10], rcx
    L0023: cmp dword [rip+0xbe99e], 0x0
    L002a: jz L0031
    L002c: call 0x7ffba9596980
    L0031: nop
    L0032: mov dword [rbp-0x14], 0x2
    L0039: mov eax, [rbp-0x14]
    L003c: mov [rbp-0x1c], eax
    L003f: mov eax, [rbp-0x14]
    L0042: inc eax
    L0044: mov [rbp-0x20], eax
    L0047: mov eax, [rbp-0x14]
    L004a: inc eax
    L004c: mov [rbp-0x14], eax
    L004f: mov eax, [rbp-0x14]
    L0052: mov [rbp-0x24], eax
    L0055: mov eax, [rbp-0x14]
    L0058: inc eax
    L005a: mov [rbp-0x14], eax
    L005d: mov eax, [rbp-0x1c]
    L0060: imul eax, [rbp-0x20]
    L0064: imul eax, [rbp-0x24]
    L0068: mov [rbp-0x14], eax
    L006b: mov eax, [rbp-0x14]
    L006e: mov [rbp-0x18], eax
    L0071: nop
    L0072: jmp L0074
    L0074: mov eax, [rbp-0x18]
    L0077: lea rsp, [rbp-0x10]
    L007b: pop rsi
    L007c: pop rdi
    L007d: pop rbp
    L007e: ret
```

Ужс.

Давайте подчищу, а адреса в стеке заменю именами переменных

```
C.M1()
    L0032: mov dword [x], 0x2 ; x = 2
    L0039: mov eax, [x]       ; eax = x
    L003c: inc eax            ; eax++
    L003e: mov [tmp], eax     ; tmp = eax
    L0041: mov eax, [x]       ; eax = x
    L0044: inc eax            ; eax++
    L004c: mov [y], eax       ; y = eax
    L004f: mov eax, [x]       ; eax = x
    L0052: inc eax            ; eax++
    L0054: mov [x], eax       ; x = eax
    L0057: mov eax, [tmp]     ; eax = tmp
    L005a: imul eax, [y]      ; eax *= y
    L0074: ret                ; return eax

C.M2()
    L0032: mov dword [x], 0x2 ; x = 2
    L0039: mov eax, [x]       ; eax = x
    L003c: inc eax            ; eax++
    L003e: mov [tmp], eax     ; tmp = eax
    L0041: mov eax, [x]       ; eax = x
    L0044: inc eax            ; eax++
    L004c: mov [tmp2], eax    ; tmp2 = eax
    L004f: mov eax, [x]       ; eax = x
    L0052: inc eax            ; eax++
    L0054: mov [x], eax       ; x = eax
    L0057: mov eax, [tmp]     ; eax = tmp
    L005a: imul eax, [tmp2]   ; eax *= tmp2
    L0074: ret                ; return eax

C.M3()
    L0032: mov dword [x], 0x2 ; x = 2
    L0039: mov eax, [x]       ; eax = x
    L003c: mov [tmp], eax     ; tmp = eax
    L003f: mov eax, [x]       ; eax = x
    L0042: inc eax            ; eax++
    L0044: mov [tmp2], eax    ; tmp2 = eax
    L0047: mov eax, [x]       ; eax = x
    L004a: inc eax            ; eax++
    L0052: mov [tmp3], eax    ; tmp3 = eax
    L0055: mov eax, [x]       ; eax = x
    L0058: inc eax            ; eax++
    L005a: mov [x], eax       ; x = eax
    L005d: mov eax, [tmp]     ; eax = tmp
    L0060: imul eax, [tmp2]   ; eax *= tmp2
    L0064: imul eax, [tmp3]   ; eax *= tmp3
    L007e: ret                ; return eax
```

Собственно, вот логика компилятора, как на ладони. Надо на шарп перевести?

Глубинный смысл всех этих изворотов в том, что операция постинкремента происходит после вычисления результата выражения, но до присваивания в эту же переменную. То есть постинкремент будет учтен только тогда если присваивание будет не в эту же переменную. Это логически защищает разработчика от неявного поведения.

То есть если ты что-то присвоил, то там будет то, что ты присвоил по состоянию на начало выполнения следующего операнда. Если бы постинкремент отрабатывал после присваивания, было бы непонятно, почему я присвоил одно, а в результате там другое. Никакой магии, только то что явно читается в коде.

---

Другими словами, если взять вот такое выражение на любом из языков

```
x = x++;
```

То на C++ получим такое

```
x = x;
x = x + 1;
```

Операция постинкремента выполняется после присваивания

А на C# получим такое

```
tmp = x;
x = x + 1;
x = tmp;
```

То есть постинкремент выполняется между вычислением выражения и присваиванием, что гарантирует что в переменной будет то, что ты туда присвоил, без магии.

Comment: было бы неплохо, ну кооменты справа норм, только если везде

Comment: @Artem добавил пояснение. Комменты дописать справа?

Comment: да, а в чем ошибка была? тот вариант тоже норм для наглядности

Comment: @Artem в том что наглядость там не совпала с реальной картиной.

Comment: Деды решают везде)

Comment: @Artem фух, дописал комменты, надеюсь без опечаток

Answer (score 2):

В C++ и C# разные правила, которые касаются порядка вычисления операндов. Тема непростая, придётся погрузиться в детали.

Посмотрим на выражение `a * b + c * d`. Здесь у нас оператор `+` с операндами `a * b` и `c * d`. Вопрос — при вычислении значения выражения, какой из операндов будет вычислен первым?

Часто (ошибочно) предлагают смотреть на ассоциативность операторов. Плюс ассоциативен слева направо, поэтому кажется, что сначала будет вычислен операнд `a * b`, а потом — `c * d`. В действительно, ассоциативность — это совсем другая штука.

Ассоциативность слева направо касается сложных выражений, в которых плюс встречается два и более раз:

```
u + v + t + s = ((u + v) + t) + s
```

Операнды `u`, `v` и т.д., могут быть вычислены в другом порядке. Здесь это обычные переменные и может быть не совсем понятно, что значит "вычислены". Но замените `u` на `a * b`, а `v` на `c * d` — и станет очевидно, что операнды могут быть сложным выражениями.

Если при вычислении операндов нет побочных эффектов, то это не имеет значения. Но операции `i++`, `++i`, `i += 10` имеют побочный эффект.

Для них порядок вычисления операндов становится очень важным.

В C++ и C# используются разные правила. C++ это наследник C, и в этих языках важна производительность. В C++ порядок вычисления операндов не определён и может отличаться у разных компиляторов и даже у одного компилятора с разными флагами.

В C# важна предсказуемость. Здесь операнды всегда вычисляются слева направо.

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/eval_order — статья про Order of Evaluation в C++.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-language/precedence-and-order-of-evaluation?view=msvc-170 — Order of Evaluation в C#.

P.S.

В C/C++ гарантирован порядок вычисления операндов у операторов `&&` и `||` — всегда слева направо.

Comment: Тоже правильно, читал про эту фишку

Comment: В C/C++ гарантирован порядок вычисления операндов у операторов && и || — всегда слева направо. - кажется я читал, что в С 98 не гарантирован. Но могу ошибаться

Comment: @Artem, так было сделано с самого начала. Иначе не работали бы штуки типа `i < length && a[i] != 5`. Правая часть будет выполняться только если истинна левая.